# Show that the number of planted plane trees on 2m + 1 vertices in which every vertex has an even number of upward branches is (1/2m+1) 3mCm

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Show that the number of planted plane trees on 2m + 1 vertices in which every vertex has an even number of upward branches is (1/2m+1) * (3m choose m )
Please help me solve this question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The basic idea is to use the recursive structure of these trees to derive an equation satisfied by their generating function, and then use Lagrange inversion to extract the coefficients. Try that, and [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4418061/edit) your question with your efforts.